# Graphql Server cannot be reached in nextjs production

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-server

i tested it in locally it work perfectly to fetch data from graphql. But, it up to production version the playground show message **Server cannot be reached**. What's the different in my locally and production server?

1. i setup server manually in digitalOcean. It is in nginx and pm2 to start the web.
2. i had install the mongdb in my server.
3. this project created from nextjs framework

Below that is my ApolloServer Code:

```
    import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-micro";
    import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
    import { schema } from "@/apollo/schema";

    let db;

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      playground: true,
      context: async ({ res, req }) => {
        if (!db) {
          try {
            const dbClient = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
              useNewUrlParser: true,
              useUnifiedTopology: true,
            });
    
            if (!dbClient.isConnected()) await dbClient.connect();
            db = dbClient.db("databaseName");
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(`error while connecting with graphql context (db):`;
          }
        }
        return { db, res, req };
      },
    });
    
    export const config = {
      api: {
        bodyParser: false,
      },

};

export default apolloServer.createHandler({ path: "/api/graphql" });
```

**Updated: Solved**
Is the uri wrong? that is my website url.

```
return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode,
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: `http://dayfruit.staging.domian.com/api/graphql`,
      credentials: "include",
      fetch,
    }),
    cache,
  });
```

Comment: You mean you can access to production graphql playground? If this way, graphql server is actually working, but you might have input a wrong api url in playground.

Comment: @AllenWong It's not. i can open playground in production but it show Server cannot be reached. Just can open it but didn't connected.

Comment: If the graphql server crashed or not serving, playground cannot be accessible too. The playground will show "Server cannot be reached" and "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" if you set a wrong api url in playground top input field. or unless playground is hosted somewhere else from your server. So I suggest you can try to set "/data" or "/api" instead of "/api/graphql" as the path, and test if the issue is still there.

Comment: are you suggest to testing other api instead of graphql? if the api is working then i can confirm that my app is serve in same server ya?

Comment: no, i mean change the last line createHandler with path /data or /api instead of /api/graphql and test if same error happened.

Comment: yeah, the error show 404 instead of 400 errors. because it not any file in my folder is /api/index.js. it only /api/graphql in my folder only. i guess maybe my production node port is not listening? i using pm2 to run my web. but, it connected my web ya, i can view it but graphql server is failed to connected.

Comment: Hello, did you solve yet? I have the exact same issue. Works in localhost but not in production